# Can't access Opencart backend

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, opencart

I can't login to my Opencart Admin Panel because when I navigate to `www.mysite.com/admin` it is redirecting to the home page. I have disabled the `.htaccess` file and `php.ini` file. As you can see from the config file, I am hosting it on a subdomain maybe that could be the cause of the problem, I am not sure.
Here is my `config.php`

```
    <?php
    // HTTP
    define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://inaden.360mustang.com/');

    // HTTPS
    define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://inaden.360mustang.com/');

    // DIR
    define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home/mustang/public_html/inaden/catalog/');
    define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/home/mustang/public_html/inaden/system/');
    define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/home/mustang/public_html/inaden/catalog/language/');
    define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/home/mustang/public_html/inaden/catalog/view/theme/');
    define('DIR_CONFIG', '/home/mustang/public_html/inaden/system/config/');
    define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/mustang/public_html/inaden/image/');
    define('DIR_CACHE', '/home/mustang/public_html/inaden/system/cache/');
    define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/home/mustang/public_html/inaden/system/download/');
    define('DIR_UPLOAD', '/home/mustang/public_html/inaden/system/upload/');
    define('DIR_MODIFICATION', '/home/mustang/public_html/inaden/system/modification/');
    define('DIR_LOGS', '/home/mustang/public_html/inaden/system/logs/');
//database details omitted
?>
```

and here is my `admin/config.php`

```
<?php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://inaden.360mustang.com/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'http://inaden.360mustang.com/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER',  'http://inaden.360mustang.com/admin/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'http://inaden.360mustang.com/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home/mustang/public_html/inaden/admin/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/home/mustang/public_html/inaden/system/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/home/mustang/public_html/inaden/admin/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/home/mustang/public_html/inaden/admin/view/template/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', '/home/mustang/public_html/inaden/system/config/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/mustang/public_html/inaden/image/');
define('DIR_CACHE', '/home/mustang/public_html/inaden/system/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/home/mustang/public_html/inaden/system/download/');
define('DIR_UPLOAD', '/home/mustang/public_html/inaden/system/upload/');
define('DIR_LOGS', '/home/mustang/public_html/inaden/system/logs/');
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', '/home/mustang/public_html/inaden/system/modification/');
define('DIR_CATALOG', '/home/mustang/public_html/inaden/catalog/');

//database details omitted 
?>
```

Comment: Both config files are correct. Have you renamed your admin folder? Or is there any `vqmod` or `ocmod` script you have used?

Comment: No I have not renamed my admin folder and there is no `vqmod` or `ocmod`. But how would that affect the redirection.

Comment: Try to reinstall opencart on your domain. Before that take backup of your current store and clear `config.php` files. Then `install` again. It will rewrite your config files but will not remove your files.  But make sure you have a backup so you can restore it if any problem occur.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem also, but after investigating I noticed that there is a file in admin/config.php which has been added for security and another to only allow a certain IP address to access the admin area. After editing them accordingly I had access to my admin area once again. 
Will definitely leave that code in for security purposes.